# Is it possible to use <tags> in .textContent or a workaround for it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm supposed to get a lot of data from a sqlite file and only use html/css/js in return to post it on the website. Here is an example of how data is posted in a single cell:

`<statistics>theres just a lot of boring text and numerous tags</statistics><br><br><extras>bla bla bla<br> more bla and bla<br> and some more bla</extras>`

I have about 160 cells, and some are longer than the above. I tried looking into custom tags but it doesn't seem like it's really supported yet and there are so many negative comments on it that it doesn't sound like it'd be something one would want to use. Is there any easy way to be able to copy paste the cells into an array and create classes for the tags and be done with it? I tried it but it won't work that easily, if I keep the tags inside " " it will return the entire text without going through the < > and if I try to get it working with +'s I'll get an error for unknown identifier for the < > i believe. I tried changing `<statistics>` to `<span style="statistics>text here</span>`, but it wont let me put any type of tags within textContent.

The only way I can think of getting it to work, but would take some extra work and seems like a lot of storage in arrays would be to seperate everything. For example:

```
var cells = [];
cells[0] = [];
cells[0].text = [ "theres just a lot of boring text and numerous tags", "bla bla bla etc" ]
cells[0].style = [ "statistics", "extras" ]
```

and use that to load the data, taking the text and style separately, but it seems inefficient and ugly, am I doing it wrong or overlooking a simpler way? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of is to use the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) property instead of the `textContent`

> `innerHTML` sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.

Comment: You probably want `<div class="statsTest">`. The `style` tag is for inline CSS (eg. `style="color: red"`).

Comment: I've really been up too long..Thanks so m uch for your help, sorry for wasting your time.